# Get intermediate time periods in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, transformation

I want to generate a table in SQL of intermediate joined states. E.g. I have the following table

```
status_1    status_2    start_date_V1   end_date_v1 start_date_2    end_date_v2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A           B            01Jan2018      31Jul2018   31Dec2017        31Jan2018
A           C            01Jan2018      31Jul2018   01Feb2018        30Dec2018
```

In this table there are start and end dates of the different states "status_1" and "status_2". I wan to have the information about the changes of the two joined states. The desired table would be:

```
status_1    status_2    start_date  end_date
-----------------------------------------------
A           B           01Jan2018   31Jan2018
A           C           01Feb2018   31Jul2018
```

The following image might help to understand the problem:
[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please explain the logic for getting the results you want.  It is not clear what the dates in the result set have to do with the dates in the original data.

Comment: is that a "date" date or a varchar date?

Comment: The date is "date" date.

Comment: To the logic: Each row indicates from when the combination of status_1 & status_2 is valid. A & B is only valid between 01Jan2018 and 31Jan2018. A&C is only valid between 01Feb2018 and 31Jul2018

Comment: How are you working that out? Telling us what it represents without telling us how it does doesn't tell us what we need.

Comment: Why is *A&C only valid between 2018-02-01 and 2018-07-01* though? Why is `start_Date_2` AFTER `end_date_2` in that first record? This isn't making sense.

Comment: Why is the `start_date` and `end_date` in the first record of your result set the same day? How is that derived from the source table. I'm baffled.

Comment: Oh OK, thx @JNevill. I edit the decription now start_date_2 is before end_date_2

Comment: start_date and end_date in the first row are not the same date. start date is the beginning of January and end date the end of January

Comment: Does a particular state always have the same date range no matter what column it is in?  In other words if we added more rows that contained State A, would the date range always have to be 01Jan2018 to 31Jul2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need the intersecting time period(?), that'd be solved with a simple 'CASE-WHEN-ELSE'-statement for each date in the query result.

```
SELECT
    [status1],
    [status2],
    [start_date] = CASE WHEN [start_date_V1] < [start_date_2] THEN [start_date_V1] ELSE [start_date_2] END,
    [end_date] = CASE WHEN [end_date_v1] < [end_date_v2] THEN [end_date_v1] ELSE [end_date_v2] END
FROM Table
```

If you've got many date columns (known amount), it'd be cleaner to type it as below. However, beware that sub queries like this can slow down your queries tremendously, if you don't know what you're doing.

```
SELECT 
    Status1, 
    Status2,
    -- New Name         Name of custom group of values     Column1       Column2            Name of custom group of values
    --    |                         |                       |               |                       |
    [start_date] = (SELECT MAX(StartDate) FROM (VALUES (start_date_1), (start_date_2)) AS value(StartDate)),
    [end_date] = (SELECT MIN(EndDate) FROM (VALUES (end_date_1), (end_date_2)) AS value(EndDate))
FROM Table
```

Comment: This is possible if I only have two states. However, is there a generalization possible if I have n states?

Comment: Is "n" a known number? I understand that comparing 5-10 columns in a case-when is no fun. If "n" is not a known number it'd have to involve a loop i reckon.

Comment: I added more friendly version for handling many date columns, if the number of date columns is static. If the number of date column isn't known, or changing, you'd have to use dynamic SQL and a loop / cursor.